# How to make slf4j notice logback.xml?

Tags: java, xml, logging, logback, slf4j

The pom contains following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
```

Currently the logger is working, in that it logs all messages correctly to the console. However, it seems to be ignoring the configurations in the logback.xml file which is located under resources. I can write any gibberish in this xml file and there is no error whatsoever, so I guess it is just not being picked up?

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="packagename" level="info" />

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you have actually included logback as dependency? Right now it seems you use slf4j-simple as logging backend. You have to remove that and add logback. Also you have mixed versions of slf4j. Make sure, you use the same version for all dependencies.

Comment: @dunni Thank you! After removing slf4j simple and parent, and adding logback core and classic, the problem was solved. Regarding the slf4j versions, I previously had an error "NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" to which the solution I found was to use version 1.6. as it contained the LoggerFactory. So to make it consistent I would have to use 1.6 for all slf4j... but now it gives the warning: 
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
Do you have any idea what to do? Sorry for asking again..

Comment: There is no reason not to use slf4j 1.7.x. If you get such errors, it might be because of corrupted JAR downloads, in that case clean up your local Maven repository and try to redownload the dependencies again. LoggerFactory is part of all slf4j versions.

Comment: i see.. okay, thanks for the help!